# How to cross reference two fields?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I want to cross reference two fields, by date and by break period.

**Base Sheet**

[image]

**Report Sheet**

[image]

So far I have tried doing a match function inside the vlookup as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,'[metric example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$C,MATCH(C1,'[metric example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),0)
```

It only will work for Team 1, but I cannot get it working for Team 2 and Team 3

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Where does that formula belong? And I am not seeing the problem. Why can you not just use `=B1` in cell C2 and fill?

Comment: I am trying to fill the base sheet.

Comment: Oh thought it was the other way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula `=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'[metric example.xlsx]Sheet1'!A"&MATCH($C$1,'[metric example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,0),TRUE),ROW()-4,COLUMN())`

Comment: is there a way to make it auto update the reference without having the report sheet up? if i close it and change the date it will give me "#REF!" errors